# Removing Flags from posts

Tags: feature-request, flagging

I made a boo-boo today, while reviewing posts I misread an answer and I flagged it as "not an answer"... a second later I realized what I did and tried to rescind the flag, only to find out I couldn't. As opposed to what happens with a close vote (where there is a "Rescind Vote" button), I could not remove the flag or "rescind" it.

I know the community will review the post and simply disagree with me (heck, I disagree with myself!), but wouldn't be better if, in this cases, I can simply correct the mistake?

Is there a mechanism to do this I couldn't find? If there isn't, what would be the way to request it?

Answer (score 4):

If a post actually gets deleted, we can vote to undelete. This privilege does require 20k rep, but that still leaves 10 users capable of such action. If you notice that you improperly flagged a post but it has not yet been deleted, you can comment on it to shed some light on that situation. That will make it easier to see the post should be undeleted if it does get voted out, and also may help other moderators realize they shouldn't hop on the bandwagon.

With comment flags, either the moderators will agree or they won't. Once a comment gets deleted there's no way to retrieve it.